# Get state in React Native IOS Tab Bar

Tags: ios, reactjs, tabs, react-native

I'm a bit new to `react-native`, so I might not have understood this while reading the docs but. I have a tab bar in an `ios` app with 2 tabs.

Currently the view code for one of the tabs is in the same file as the page that loads the the Tab bar (I call this `HomeTab`). The second tab (call `Tab2`) which contains the view code for the second tab is in a separate `.js` page and is loaded into `HomeTab`.

I'm having trouble passing information in HomeTab's state to `Tab2`, and do not want to write all of `Tab2` into `HomeTab` like I did for `Tab1` because I will get a really big file.

The code structure is a bit like this:

```
    {View Code for Tab 1 here}

    <TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
            <TabBarIOS.Item
                selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'Tab1'}
                title = "Tab1"
                icon = {require('image!Tab1')}
                onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({
                        selectedTab: 'Tab1'
                    }

                    );
                }}>

                // Call Tab1 View here

            </TabBarIOS.Item>

            <TabBarIOS.Item
                selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'Tab2'}
                title = "Tab2"
                icon = {require('image!Tab2')}
                onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({
                        selectedTab: 'Tab2'
                    }
                    );
                }}>

                <Tab2/>
            </TabBarIOS.Item>
```

Intuitively I feel like all I am doing is putting code in a separate file, so both tabs should have the same state, but when I print out anything from my state it is undefined. Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was fairly ignorant of the capabilities of javascript. I was able to pass props just by including it in the call to Tab2 like this

```
    <Tab2 propName = {some information}/>
```